# Non-English numeric formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, culture, regional-settings

In English-US, the decimal separator symbol is "."
So if I want to write the result of 100 + 25/100, it will be 100.25  (obviously).

How will I write it in a constant in Visual Studio if I'm a french developer living in France? In France they use a comma (",") as a decimal seperator.

Will I write

> const double x = 100.25

or

> const double x = 100,25

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518625/c-sharp-doubles-show-comma-instead-of-period

Answer (score 2):

You write programs in C#, not in English. Use syntax of C#.

```
const float x = 100.25
```

When you show some information for non-Englsih *user* you can format it in appropriate view.

For ex.:

```
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString().Replace(".", ",")); // or some special format functions
```

Comment: I think it is better to show in example `CultureInfo` usage. It will be more useful

Comment: also, you could not store float values in `int` variable

Comment: @Fyodor Ahaha, Yes, you are right. I have not even noticed this "little" error with int/float type :)

Upd. And thanks for "CultureInfo", I didn't know about it before.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site and people expect to read correct and self-contained answers to the question, so if you understand how to improve/correct your answer and able to do it, please do it every time.

Answer (score 1):

The first. There are no cultural variants of C# compiler, the code is compilable by any compiler. Besides that, `,` has some different usages in C# that would be incompatible, e.g. separating entries in new List:

```
var data = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

They will have to write `100.25` too. The source code itself is independent of culture. If this wasn't the case, you'd need some way to specify the culture to the compiler.

Programmers *could* declare the values as strings and then use [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an appropriate format provider, but that would be a runtime conversion and an inefficient way to declare values known at compile time.